# Linq to SQL - Best way to work with a collection of objects inside another object

Tags: linq-to-sql, object, collections

I have a table of Items for auction and a table of bids made for those items.  There's much more to the database but we'll keep it simple.

```
public class Items
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public List<Bid> Bids { get; set; }
}

public class Bids
{
    public int BidID { get; set; }
    public int ItemID  { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public datetime BidTime { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
}
```

I want to return a dataset that includes the ItemID, the ItemName and all of the associated bid records ordered by BidTime, descending.  Finally, I'd like to only see Items that a certain Customer has bid on and I'd like to only see their bids for that item.  There is a foreign key relationship between Bids.ItemID and Items.ItemID.  I'm using Linq to SQL.

This works and appears to return the correct dataset:

```
from i in Items
from b in i.Bids
where i.AuctionID == 2 && b.CustomerID == (Int32?)1165
orderby b.BidTime descending
select new
{
    i.ItemID,
    i.ItemName,
    i.Bids
}
```

I'm a SQL guy trying to wrap my head around the OO nature of Linq.  Is this the best way (or even a good way) to get the results I want?  Is there a better way?

Thanks,

BK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one (slightly more simple syntax):

**Updated where clause due to comment**

```
from i in db.items
where i.AuctionID == 2 && i.Bids.Any(c=>c.CustomerID == (Int32?)1165)
select new
{ i.ItemId,
  i.ItemName,
  i.Bids.Where(b=>b.CustomerID == (Int32?)1165 ).OrderbyDescending(b=>b.BidTime)
 }
```

Make sure you profile the sql and verify that you get only ONE sql statement. If not, you need to have to add LoadOptions to your datacontext (that will make sure all the bids are eager loaded with your items).

This one will also order the bids per item (not sure if yours will do the same.... but  I guess you checked that).

Comment: Thanks Pleun!  I had to make a couple edits to fix up the anonymous type.  You are correct in assuming I wanted the Bids ordered by BidTime within each Item.  There is one problem with the result set.  It returns every Item in the Items table and only populates the Bids IEnumerable for the Items Customer 1165 bid on.  I would like the return set to only include the Items 1165 bid on.  Thanks!

Comment: BTW: You do not need the "from b in i.Bids" => that is already there due to the foreign key and is handled by Linq2sql

Comment: Actually I tried that (without the 'from bin i.Bids') and then Linq can't find CustomerID or BidTime (both fields in the Bids table).  I was able to resolve that by adding the second 'From'.  I agree with you, I thought that because of the FK I could access it directly but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Well, i.Bids is a collection (multiple bids) so it does not have a customerID so you need to use things like .Any .First etc.